# How to move boxes onto another line in html, css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I've got a section on my webpage called Roles avaliable and I want the title to be at the top and then the jobs to be on the next line. But right now they are all showing on the same line. I have them in a row and the separate divs. So how can I fix this?? Here is my html code for it:

```css
.compLeft {
            
            border-style: solid;
            border-radius: 0.625rem;
            border: 0px #d4d4d4 solid;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0px 10px 15px -3px, rgb(0 0 0 / 5%) 0px 4px 6px -2px;
            margin-left: 4rem;
            
        }
    
        .compRight {
            
            border-style: solid;
            border-radius: 0.625rem;
            border: 0px #d4d4d4 solid;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0px 10px 15px -3px, rgb(0 0 0 / 5%) 0px 4px 6px -2px;
            margin-left: 4rem;
    
        }
```

```html
 <div className="row">
    
      <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center", display: "block" }}><u><b>Roles Available: 2</b></u></h3>
    
      <div
        class="compLeft"
        style={{
          padding: "20px",
          width: "17%", position: "relative", display: "block"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ marginBottom: "20px", }}>
    
          <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
            <img
              src={filterFunction().logo}
    
              alt="programmer"
              height="70px"
              width="70px"
    
            ></img>
          </div>
          <h3 style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px", }}>{filterFunction().vacancies[0].jobTitle}</h3>
    
          <div className="compDesc">
            <p style={{ marginTop: "10px", }}>{filterFunction().vacancies[0].jobDescription}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    
        <div style={{
          marginTop: "20px", position: "absolute",
          bottom: "0", marginBottom: "10px"
        }}>
          <p style={{ marginTop: "0px", lineHeight: "16pt" }}>{filterFunction().vacancies[0].location}</p>
        </div>
    
    
    
      </div>
    
    
      <div
        class="compRight"
        style={{
          padding: "20px",
          width: "17%", position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        <div class="rowComp" style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
    
          <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
            <img
              src={filterFunction().logo}
    
              alt="programmer"
              height="70px"
              width="70px"
              style={{ marginLeft: "0px" }}
            ></img>
          </div>
          <h3 style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px" }}>{filterFunction().vacancies[1].jobTitle}</h3>
    
          <div className="compDesc">
            <p style={{ marginTop: "10px", }}>{filterFunction().vacancies[1].jobDescription}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    
        <div style={{
          marginTop: "20px", position: "absolute",
          bottom: "0", marginBottom: "15px"
        }}>
          <p style={{ marginTop: "0px", lineHeight: "16pt" }}>{filterFunction().vacancies[1].location}</p>
        </div>
    
    
    
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: most likely problem that `.row` has `display: flex`, remove `className="row"` from first div

Comment: But now the jobs are on top of each other and they need to be beside each other

Comment: then add `display: flex` to parent div https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/